# Direction of $\vec{D}$, $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{P}$ fields in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, dielectric

The relations $\vec{D}=\epsilon \vec{E}$, and $\vec{P} = \chi \epsilon_0 \vec{E}$ imply that all three fields have the same direction. Is this always true in the case of static source charges and some dielectric material surrounding the charges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The general relation is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation) $$\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0\mathbf{E} +\mathbf{P}.$$
Within 1) linear response and in materials that are 2à isotropic and 3) homogeneous we can write:
$$
\mathbf{P}=\epsilon_0\chi_e\mathbf{E}\rightarrow\mathbf{D}= \epsilon_0( \chi_e+1)\mathbf{E}=\epsilon\mathbf{E}
$$
(see [Electric susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility).) It is true that linear dielectrics constitute a very large class of materials, but this is by no means a general rule. In particular, some materials or at the microscopic level, or the susceptibility (or polarizability) are tensors and the direction of polarization is not the same as that of the electric field (although at the microscopic level we wouldn't use macroscopic description in terms of $\mathbf{D}$):
See [polarizability tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability#Tensor).

**Related:** [Understanding the Susceptibility Tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/288106/247642)

Answer (score 3):

The image is from [WikiPedia's description of ferroelectric material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity). The black parts are from Wikipedia and the red parts are my additions. If we look at a point on the left shoulder of the hysteresis curve, we see that $E<0$ but $P>0$ there. In other words, $E$ and $P$ point in opposite directions.[image]

Comment: another example is birefringent materials ($\epsilon$ is a matrix that isn't proportional to $I$); it will make an angle between $E$ and $P$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is always true, but the very relations you give. But note that these equations apply to *linear* dielectrics. Not all materials are linear dielectrics, so not all materials have those relations apply. In a nonlinear dielectric, these three vectors can point in different directions.